# SpringRunner/JUnit running/testing a private (non-test) method

Tags: java, spring, junit

We have a Spring 5 application using JUnit 4 as our test harness (w/ `SpringRunner`). We're experiencing an issue where a private helper method that's *not marked* with a `@Test` annotation is being run as a test. This happens in **both IntelliJ and Maven**.

The method signature is:

```
private Optional<TestSuiteJsonObject> createTestSuite(String name, TestType type) throws IOException, LicenseException {
```

And the test class itself looks like:

```
public class TestSuitesControllerTest extends ControllerTest
```

There are no annotations on either. The `ControllerTest` looks like:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT, classes = CompanyTestApplication.class)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@Ignore
public class ControllerTest {
   ...
}
```

The **behavior** is that these test methods are run with `null` arguments. We don't want them to be run at all. The rest of the methods in this class are appropriately marked with the `@Test` annotation.

I wondered if the fact that the word `test` is in the class/method name could be causing JUnit to identify it as runnable, but **changing the names** of both the class and method has no effect.

Adding `@Ignore` to the private method also has no effect!

What are we doing wrong? Did we step into an alternate dimension where test harnesses are actually testing stress responses of the engineers?

[image]

Comment: Don't know much about SpringRunner but possibly it's because of the name word 'test' appeared in the method? Can you change it to something else? or maybe add `@Ignore` to it

Comment: I've tried both - making the method `createSuite()`, and adding an `@Ignore` annotation, and in both/either case it continues to run.

Comment: yeah, sorry didn't read the full question earlier

Comment: You can always move that method to a helper class. I would however suggesting to rename it to something other then `createSuite` and `createTestSuite` as it might be that JUnit uses that as some magic factory methods to create a test-suite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a silly mistake, but I'm leaving it for any future folk who find themselves in the same situation.

I had **two methods** with the same name. The test method:

```
@Test
@WithMockUser(username = "admin", roles = "ADMIN")
public void createSuite() throws Exception { ... }
```

And the helper method:

```
private static Optional<TestSuiteJsonObject> createSuite(String name, TestType type) { ... }
```

And we somehow glossed over this. ‍♂️